# My computer restarts automatically when there is power outage and the monitor is turned on, using UPS power

Tags: power-supply, ups

I have a Zebronics Power UPS which backs up the system power at the time of power outage. I have no issues with that. But yesterday night I kept a movie to download and slept turning off just my monitor and in the morning there was power outage in the house. So, I tried to turn on the monitor (pressed the button on monitor) and suddenly the computer restarted.

I checked if there is any problem with my UPS. So, I myself turned off the switch that provides current, but this time the monitor was on and UPS backed up the system without any problem.

So this problem is occurring only when I turn off my monitor. Please do help me with this problem

Comment: Sounds like the spike in voltage/current being used that occurred when turning on the monitor was enough to drop what your computer needed to run momentarily

Comment: I agree. The UPS can't provide as much current as an outlet. When you turned on the monitor, the inrush current was enough to pull the UPS voltage down for a second. This caused your computer to reboot. Can you repeat the problem? (Turn off display, turn off UPS supply power, turn on display). If it happens every time, or even some of the time, consider up-sizing your UPS.

Comment: Is your monitor a CRT, CCFL LCD, or LED LCD?